# UserInfo.getProfileID() Does Not Work Once I Change the ID

Tags: apex, profile

My developer is off for the week and I need to change a wee bit of code. I do not know much Apex.

Current code to make Admin exempt

```
//System Admin is exempt, 00e80000000k3t2AAA id of System Admin Profile
    if(UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00e80000000k3t2AAA'){
        System.debug('Admin exempt from Invoice & Billing Period validation.');
        return true;
    }
```

All I want to do is just change the Admin ID to a custom profile ID so users can continue their work.

When I change the ID to

```
//System Admin is exempt, 00e80000000k3t2AAA id of System Admin Profile
    if(UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00e80000001SQTxAAA'){
        System.debug('Admin exempt from Invoice & Billing Period validation.');
        return true;
    }
```

It will not let the user under that profile be exempt.

I have tried id `00e80000001SQTxAAA` and `00e80000001SQTx`.

Any ideas of how to get the custom profile id to work?

Comment: you should not be using a hard coded profile Id as this will fail if you move it to another environment as any ids are specifice to each instance.

Comment: This is the same ID in the sandbox as in the live org. They were copied over from the live org. Any other ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't do this- wait for your developer to come back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly run a SOQL query to retrieve profile name and use that in the code as follows:

```
String profileName = [Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:Userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;

if(profileName == 'System Administrator'){
    System.debug('Admin exempt from Invoice & Billing Period validation.');
    return true;
}
```

This will eliminate the Id dependency for different orgs.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I understand this is not best practices with the IDs and I will get with my developer when she comes back. I appreciate you helping me out in the meantime so my users aren't in a bind for month end and year end financials. I need to get better at this Apex coding thing ;)